# R Shiny app shows old data

Tags: shiny

I have shiny app, which is displaying old data (4 days delay!) though on the server data are refreshed (current day).

What is strange the old dataset does not exist on the server - seems only existing in Shiny cache.

On the server I have 1 dataset done by cron on May 18, and 1 dataset done by manual refresh 24 May. However Data in the app are from May 20! In the report I display date of dataset creation time - that's why I know the data does not exist any more.

Is it posible to reset Shiny cache somehow?

I also have simmilar problems for some other reports. What is strange for some reports it happends, for some not ...

Comment: Currently I have a cron task in /etc/cron.hourly/ that is suppose to deal with cache problems: touch $(find /data/shiny-server/www -iname "server.R")
touch $(find /data/shiny-server/www -iname "ui.R")

Comment: Did you put your data fetching step outside of shiny? If so, that part of scripts will only be run once since they were deployed or the shiny server restarts.

Comment: Data fetching is done by sql run by R, part of shiny. However Shiny server is restarted every day, so it was strange for me I had 4 days delay though fresh data were avaiable on the server... Is fetching data in R/shiny not allowed/recommended? I still need to do it in Shiny - if crond deos not refresh it correctly I do run manual update in shiny app on entry, other way I would need to use not fresh data.

Comment: Of course, shiny needs to fetch data to get something to display. lol What I meant is that you need to make sure your data fetching step is inside `shinyServer()`. Also why do you have shiny server restarting every day?

Comment: Data updates are done in 2 ways - 1. is done via cron -> not using shiny server, but updated data file si visible for shiny report. 2. in server.R there is source("readdata.R") which updates if cron didnt work or last manual update was not fresh. Why restarting daily? server admin set it this way because sometimes sth failed (refreshing most probably) , the admin not working for us any more so hard to recall exact reasons :) But restarting itself should not be an issue...

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, however, in case anyone has this issue and stumbles across this question here an answer embedded deep in the closed issues of the [shiny development](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1882).

**Solution**

Your UI is probably not a function, and so it is being cached by Shiny for performance reasons. If you don't want the caching, just make it into a function (however, this does mean that you lose the slight performance benefit of UI caching).

Turn this:

```
ui <- fluidPage(...)
```

into this:

```
ui <- function(req) {
  fluidPage(...)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have been struggling with this problem for quite a while, and thought I had tried everything, including putting a js button on the shiny sidebar to manually refresh (unfortunately that did not work either). There are two things that did work for me:

1. Make sure all code to read data from files is in a code chunk with name `global` OR
2. Manually restart the shiny server when new data is uploaded

Obviously the first one is much more manageable, and a solution that I wish I had known weeks ago when I started playing with workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

I found that cache of R Shiny server is updated when the date of creation for the file "app.R" is changed.

So, here is the trick I used:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

   # Trick file date creation update
   onStop(function() {

     # File name
     p <- paste0(getwd(), "/app.R")

     # Update file 'date creation'
     Sys.setFileTime(p, now())

  }) # onStop

 ...


} # server
```

The idea is to update the date of "app.R" creation after each session.

Comment: Thank you but for me it only updates the last modification time