# How to prevent shinyapps.io caching?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I've created a small app using R & Shiny (that works with dynamic data) and have deployed it using shinyapps.io server for non commercial use.

It seems shiny server caches the data - every time I restart the server application's UI shows up to date information, but the next day the old data appears (data I see after the restart).

I've been looking for some information regarding this problem and found out that using:

```
ui <- function(req){
 dashboardPage(
  ...
 )
}
```

instead of:

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
 ...
)
```

should resolve the issue.

But unfortunately it doesn't work in my case and e.g. today I see the data from the moment I restarted the server.

Does anyone has an idea on how to resolve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried contacting shinyapps representatives? Sounds like something that might be connected with their product, not the code per se?

Comment: I haven't. I was trying to modify server's settings but unfortunately it seems there is no such an option that could help me. If there is no solution for my problem I'll contact them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37408072/r-shiny-app-shows-old-data) (no idea how I missed it before)

It seems that moving all the data fetching to the

```
server <- function(){}
```

resolved the problem.