# Flexdashboard (shiny) doesn't update with new data

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I made this flexdashboard: https://corona.berndschmidl.com/oesterreich/ which reads in data from Wikipedia and shows it. Till yesterday I was able to update the dashboard with restarting the shiny server. Now this doesn't work anymore. I'm aware that it has something to do with the cache but I tried everything I found here and on Google with no success. This is kind of important and therefore pretty frustrating.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: depending on how long the data processing takes, you could think of putting your data fetching method in the server so that data is re-fetched for every user visiting the site. PS I like the dygraphs!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R Shiny app shows old data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37408072/r-shiny-app-shows-old-data)

Comment: Putting all file reading/refreshing code in a chunk labeled `global` works.

Comment: As I got up this morning it was working again. Thanks for your comments, i tried all of them before. So I really don't know what is the cause for it to sometimes update and sometimes not.