# Is it possible to clear the Shiny cache when reloading an app?

Tags: r, caching, input, shiny, restart

Is it possible to clear the Shiny cache history when reloading an app? Specifically, I have a textInput for adding a title that doesn't clear when the app is restarted. In other words, all of the titles entered into the app on previous runs have been "remembered" and show up in a dropdown list when the app is rerun or restarted again. I have tried using shinyjs::reset, but that clears the current value and not the ones in the "history". I've also tried updateTextInput with an action button set to " ", but also clears only the current value and not the ones in the "history". I have also tried setting ui as a function using:

ui <- function(req) {
fluidPage(...)
}

as well as:

I found that cache of R Shiny server is updated when the date of creation for the file "app.R" is changed.

So, here is the trick I used:

server <- function(input, output, session) {

Trick file date creation update
onStop(function() {

```
 # File name
 p <- paste0(getwd(), "/app.R")

 # Update file 'date creation'
 Sys.setFileTime(p, now())
```

}) # onStop

} # server
The idea is to update the date of "app.R" creation after each session.

Neither of these solutions worked for me. Finally, I found this post:

I also found this post:

I have been struggling with this problem for quite a while, and thought I had tried everything, including putting a js button on the shiny sidebar to manually refresh (unfortunately that did not work either). There are two things that did work for me:

1. Make sure all code to read data from files is NOT in a code chunk with a name OTHER THAN `global` OR
2. Manually restart the shiny server when new data is uploaded

Obviously the first one is much more manageable, and a solution that I wish I had known weeks ago when I started playing with workarounds.

But I am not sure what is involved in implementing either, so if someone could clarify that, that would be great.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please post sample code and what you have tried

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R Shiny app shows old data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37408072/r-shiny-app-shows-old-data)

Comment: No, as mentioned in the question, I've tried the solutions listed in that post and none of them work.