# Stop R Shiny from restoring selected inputs on page refresh

Tags: r, shiny

Whenever a user refreshes a page, any UI element that has been interacted with retains its new value instead of reverting to its default.
E.g. if I run the app below, change any of the inputs, then refresh the page, the new values are kept rather than the widgets being restored to 'A'.
I can appreciate this is useful in many situations, but is there a way to stop it from within Shiny, or is it controlled by the browser's cache? A hard refresh (ctrl F5) does indeed reset them back to 'A'.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput("select", "Values", LETTERS[1:5], selected='A'),
    radioButtons("radio", "Radio", LETTERS[1:5], selected='A'),
    checkboxGroupInput("check", "Checkbox", LETTERS[1:5], selected='A')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: R Shiny always restores old selections. I use `updateRadioButtons()`, `updateSelectInput()`,`updateCheckboxGroupInput()`. But it's not global. Look at  [Is it possible to clear the Shiny cache when reloading an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68736332/10489562) and  [R Shiny app shows old data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37408072/r-shiny-app-shows-old-data) and [Github; Sys.Date() providing date of last server restart, answer from  daattali](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1882#issuecomment-341954284)  linked by last SO link.

Comment: I can reproduce this using Firefox (Chrome doesn't restore the selections). I don't think it is expected behaviour: `If you reload a shiny application by clicking on your browser’s Reload button, it will start a new session on both the client and the server, losing the state on both sides.` - [source](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reconnecting.html). I'd filed an issue [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/3763).

Comment: Yep I am indeed using Firefox! I'll follow that bug report, I'm intrigued to see why this is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot really reproduce the problem, here's a GIF of what happens on my system when I refresh the browser (`Chrome Version 94.0.4606.71`):

[image: Screenshot of Chrome Browser showing that a refresh resets the inputs]

Comment: Interesting, I am indeed using Firefox. That seems to answer it, and I'm happy with this for now as the majority of my users will be on Chrome.